# FirebaseUser getCurrentUser bug. Always return previous user id

Tags: android, firebase

Using Firebase auth. So I need to get current user Id. If user1 logged out and user2 logged in it suppose to return me id of user2 because current session use user2 credentials. But for some reason if user1 logged out and user2 logged in when call 'getUid()' it returns me uid of previous credentials of user1

`FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();`

Comment: If you think there is a bug, then send your reproduction steps to Firebase support directly.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When logging out a user, you need to call the method `signOut()`:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()
```

When you call this, the id will change

Comment: im using `AuthUI.getInstance().signOut()` so its two different authentication?

Comment: Authui will sign the user out also, but are u also logging in using authui api?? Authui is just to bind firebase with ui.. The above method I provided is here https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth#signOut()

Comment: @BorisRuzanov authui is a library https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/README.md#authui-sign-in if you are signing in using it then u need to sign out also using it

Comment: If question helped you please upvote it as well x))))